# PHP function return false && true && false?

Tags: php, function, return

Upgrading from PrestaShop 1.6 to 1.7, I found a change in how the developers return the module install method. Obviously, for both the old and new way, you want to return true if ALL is ok, and false
1.6:

```
public function install() {
    if(!$this->someFunction() || !parent::install()) 
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Sometimes the other way around:

```
public function install() {
    if($this->someFunction() && parent::install()) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But now in 1.7 they do it this way, and I cannot figure out how this even works:

```
public function install() {
    return parent::install()
        && $this->someFunction();
}
```

How can a function return THIS and THAT? If I was to guess, I would think that it either returns the first TRUE/FALSE and then exits, OR returns the sum of them both (but then only FALSE && FALSE would return FALSE)

Please help me understand this.

Comment: return parent::install() && $this->someFunction(); 
will only return true if parent:install() is true and $this->someFunction() is also true.
Else it will return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return this && that` is read as `return (this && that)`. `this` and `that` will be evaluated to a `boolean`. If both are `true`, then it becomes `return (true && true)`. `true && true` evaluates to `true`. So, it becomes `return true`.

It's [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) in code form.

Comment: It should be noted that this is particulary valid for PHP. So `1 && 2` evaluates to `true` in PHP. In some scripting languages, e.g. JavaScript, it works similar, however, the evaluated result is one of the input operands itself. `1 && 2` in JavaScript evaluates to `2` since 1 evaluates to true and the second operand has to be checked as well, thus that second value is returned. `1 || 2` returns `1` in JS and `true` in PHP.

Comment: A-ha! It was the missing parentheses that made the confusion for me. By adding the parentheses it now makes sense :) And to state the obvious  (true && false) will off course evaluate to false.